# Is it possible to run GUI apps in windows containers?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-image, nano-server

So I'm playing around with this containers concept and specificlly windows containers.

I managed to run containers using the windows nanoserver image, however this image meant to services and does not support gui applications (or 32 bit apps).

Couldn't find any mentioning of running gui applications (and see there gui) using windows container (found only linux container gui).

is there a way to run GUI apps in containers? and so how do I can create my own image containing this support?

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, its impossible because docker does not allow rdp inside container

Answer (score 0):

The nano server is not supporting GUI. That's why I cannot see how this should work if your base image for your container is a nano server

Comment: Yeah I know that but I don't mind making my own windows image that do support, Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to make custom windows image

Comment: what about the full windowsserver image? Does it support GUI apps?

Comment: Was anyone able to figure out if the full windowsserver images supports GUI apps?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible on Windows regardless of image. It is a system limitation. As a last hope to get this somehow running I would try to install a VNC server inside a container and would try to connect to it from outside. This approach works for Linux-based containers. But I'm doubting that it will work on Windows.