# Is it possible to run GUI apps in headless Windows containers?

Tags: windows, containers, docker-for-windows, docker

This question is similar to but different from [Is it possible to run GUI apps in windows containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38601041/945131) in the following way: I do not wish to login and see the GUI.  Instead, I would like to know if is possible to start a winforms or wpf application from the commandline inside of a Windows container. If it runs at all, what are the window/screen implications for the GUI application?

Perhaps I have an GUI application that starts listening on a port when a user clicks a button. And perhaps I want to test this application in an automated way, both with a script that triggers a GUI button click also running in the container, and a script that creates and runs a container with both the GUI app and the button clicker.